# Creating an array of weekdays with an additional property and moment

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, momentjs

Using Momentjs, I am creating an array of objects, `month`. Inside this array there are two properties: `week`, and `day`. `week` is just a number, the week in the year, generated by moment. `day` is currently an array of the dates in of that week including the shoulder dates if it's the start or the end of the month (for example, last week's range would be 27 - 2, October 27th to November 2nd). Rather than having just the array of numbers, I now need the `days` property to be an object, with a `date` property that's the date in the month, and `isShoulderDate`, a boolean that will determine whether it's inside or outside of the current month.

Here's how the `month` array was previously generated.

```
    this.month = [];

    const startWeek = moment(this.selectedDate.from).startOf('month').week();
    const endWeek = moment(this.selectedDate.from).endOf('month').week();

    for (let week = startWeek; week <= endWeek; week++) {
      this.month.push({
        week: week,
        days: Array(7).fill(0).map((n, i) =>
          moment().week(week).startOf('week').clone().add(n + i, 'day').format('D')),
      });
    }
```

I have attempted to modify the `days` property a couple of different ways. My most recent attempt is:

```
    for (let week = startWeek; week <= endWeek; week++) {
      this.month.push({
        week: week,
        days: Array(7).fill({
          isShoulderDate: null,
        }),
      });
    }

    this.month.forEach((calendarWeek) => {
      calendarWeek.days.map((day, n, i) => {
        day.date = moment().week(calendarWeek).startOf('week').clone().add(n + i, 'day').format('D');
      });
    });
```

This just outputs `3` over and over in the `date` property. I'd also like to do the mapping when initially filling the array rather than having an additional `forEach` to avoid additional iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that with `Array(7).fill({  })` you are using **one** object to populate 7 slots in an array. They are not 7 objects, but just one, which you have referenced 7 times. So when you later make an update to the object referenced in the first array element, that change is visible in *all* array elements.

Here is how you could do it. The demo is for the month of May 2019:

```js
var selectedDate = { from: new Date("2019-05-01") };

this.month = [];

const curMonth = moment(this.selectedDate.from).month(); // Get the month 
const startWeek = moment(this.selectedDate.from).startOf('month').week();
const endWeek = moment(this.selectedDate.from).endOf('month').week();

for (let week = startWeek; week <= endWeek; week++) {
    let dt = moment().week(week).startOf('week');
    this.month.push({
        week: week,
        days: Array.from({length: 7}, (_, i) => ({
            date: dt.add(i ? 1 : 0, 'day').format('D'),
            isShoulderDate: dt.month() !== curMonth,
        })),
    });
}

console.log(month);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```